# Find the smallest natural number that can not be written as a sum of elements of S?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a set of natural numbers $S_1$ , $S$ and a number N .

Specification of sets are as follow .

$$S = \{1,\dots N\}$$
$$S_1\subset S \;and \;S_1=\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m\}$$

And $$S' = S\setminus S_1$$

Find the smallest natural n that can not be written as a sum of elements of S'.

Note:
A number can't be used more than once .

e.g. if $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $S_1=\{3\}$ then $S' = \{1,2\}$ we can't form $4$ using $S'$, so answer is $4$.

Can we design an algorithm to solve this problem  useing the knowledge of set $S_1$  and N?

Comment: This looks like an algorithm problem. Doubt if there is a number-theoretic way...

Comment: Yes it's like an algorithmic problem.But some how we have to come up with the  solution using number theory .

Comment: Your notations are quite confusing. I suppose you mean, $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $S_1\subset S$ (which is absolutely not what you have written).

Comment: Yes i mean that .

Comment: I can tell you the answer immediately if the set is a list of the first n powers of 2 ({1,2,4,8,16} can't make 32)

Comment: @user3805652 So if I understand correctly, do you want to write an *algorithm* that solves this problem?

Comment: This is exactly similar to the subset sum problem.

Comment: @5xum If you know the solution then it's ok  .

Comment: @user3805652 How can I know the solution if I don't know what your problem even is? What is the end result of what you are trying to do? Do you have one particular set $S$ or do you want to write an algorithm?

Comment: What does "make using" mean?

Comment: @Waffle It's not a subset problem since we already knows that numbers are consecutive and some of them have removed .The number which are removed also we have . So we have do something with removed number to find the solution to this question .

Comment: The formulation of the problem is actually very confusing. I thin it could be rephrased this way: given a set of natural numbers $S$, find the smallest natural $n$ that can not be written as a sum of elements of $S$.

Comment: @5xum Let's explain this question more . set S1 is given to us and we also know n . Then using the knowledge of S1 it's possible to find the minimum number that can't be formed .

Comment: To find the smallest number you can't make, find the smallest power 'n' of 2 you can't make and $2^{n+1}-1$ becomes your upper bound.

Comment: @Tom-Tom sorry for problem statements it has been updated .

Comment: @Waffle can you be more specific ?

Comment: @user3805652 iF $s_1$ is given, then can you write it down in your question? Or do you want an algorithm in general?

Comment: @5xum Sorry for confusion . Question is updated with more information .

Answer (score 1):

A possible rather stupid way to do it is to compute the sum $M$ of all elements of $S_1$. Form an array $a$ (filled with zeroes) with the numbers from $1$ to $M-1$. Then compute all the possible sums of elements of $S_1$ (there are $2^N-1$ such sums where $N=\text{Card}\, S_1$, the number of elements of $S_1$) and for each result $i$, put the value $a_i$ to $1$. Once you've done it, the smallest value $i$ such that $a_i=0$ is the searched result.

There are many ways to improve this algorithm, but that's a start.

If you want to improve, use polynomials and compute the product
$$ P(X)=\prod_{p\in S_1}(1+X^p)$$
The coefficient of $X^k$ in $P(X)$ is actually the number of ways to form $k$ as a sum of elements of $S_1$. So you just have to look for the smallest $k$ such that the coefficient of $X^k$ is zero. This technique does not improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just realized how simple this problem is. Here's the solution in Lua:

S={1,1,1,1,5,7,10,25,50,75,100,250,500,1000}
table.sort(S)

x=1
for i=1,#S do
if S[i]<=x then
x=x+S[i]
end
end

print(x)

Starting at x=1, go in ascending order increasing x if the number is less than or equal to x, and stop when it isn't (or when they all are).

ex.`given the set {1,1,1,1,5,9,12,31,50,100,300}
1 = 1
2 = 1+1
3 = 1+1+1
4 = 1+1+1+1
5 = 5
...
8 = 5+1+1+1
9 = 9
...
12 = 9+1+1
...
30 = 12+9+5+1+1+1+1
31 = 31
...
49 = 31+12+5+1
50 = 50
...
100 = 50+31+12+5+1+1
...
211 = 100+50+31+12+9+5+1+1+1+1
212 = X (smallest value which cannot be made)`